# AngularJS template directive with Java Play

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, angularjs-directive, playframework

I have an AngularJS application. Within that app, I am trying to load up a piece of HTML with a custom directive. My directive (in `app.js`) is as follows:

```js
app.directive('mytable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/mytable'
    };
});
```

Within my HTML file (`index.html`) then, I just specify the custom tag.

```html
<mytable></mytable>
```

The implementation details within `mytable.html` are just static HTML. On the routing side with Java Play, I have:

```
GET     /mytable                Application.mytable
```

And within my Play controllers (`Application.java`), I have:

```java
public static void mytable() { render(); }
```

However, when I try to load a page, I get:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/mytable 500 (Internal Server Error) 
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:9000/mytable".
```

Upon closer inspection, within the console, I see:

```
Template not found 
The template Application/mytable.txt does not exist.
```

How can I fix my code? And why is it trying to render `mytable.txt` instead of `mytable.html`, when all my other controllers in `Application.java` are the same and render `.html` files correctly?

Just a side note: `http://localhost:9000/mytable` does render the static content for `<mytable>` correctly.

Comment: Check Play console, 500 - it is a server error.

Comment: It is indeed a server error. But what could the problem be, given the code I wrote above? Am I specifying routing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: this applies only to Play versions 2.x*

I have the feeling that your controller's method is a bit wrong. I would rewrite this

```
public static void mytable() { render(); }
```

to:

```
public static Result mytable() { 
    ok(index.render()); 
}
```

where `index` is your view, `render` is the method you call to render this view, and your controller returns a `Result` (via the `ok()` method)

Comment: He is probably using Play1.